# XML <example> tag with : (<m:example>)

Tags: xml

I have a xml file and some tags have dots in it like this `<m:properties></m:properties>`
but when I try to read it it doesn't work.

This is the code how I read it:

```
displayCD(0);

function displayCD(i) {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp, i);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "text.xml", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(xml, i) {
var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML; 
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ENTRY");
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML =
"Artist: " +
x[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"<br>Title: " +
x[i].getElementsByTagName("type")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"<br>Year: " + 
x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"<br>Price: " + 
x[i].getElementsByTagName("body")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"<br>Price: " + 
x[i].getElementsByTagName("expires")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed>
    <ENTRY>
        <content>
            <m:properties>
                <id>41</id>
                <type>Hallo meneer</type>
                <title>MAILING</title>
                <body>Just some random content Hi !</body>
                <expires>2013-07-11</expires>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </ENTRY>
</feed>
```

and if I remove the : it works completely fine, is there anyway so I can keep the : and still read it ?

Comment: Thats called xml namespaces

Comment: @T.G I edited the post.

Comment: @Nanoc okey, I get that but how do I call the id. It doesn't work normally ?

Comment: I don't know why your most recent question was receiving downvotes, but I was about to answer it before you deleted it...

Comment: Because people are crying too fast hahah, but can you make a chat and still help me out ? @JamesDonnelly

Comment: @Goldenowner I'd rather upvote and answer the question...

Comment: The question is back @JamesDonnelly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML is not [***well-formed***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085).  One way to make it well-formed, you've found, is to remove the namespace prefix (`m:`) from `m:properties`.

Alternatively, to keep the `m:`, declare the namespace prefix:

```
<feed xmlns:m="http://www.example.com/m">
```

Without either eliminating the namespace prefix or declaring it, the XML is not well-formed and will not be parsed successfully by compliant XML parsers.